# Capture picture after unlocking screen / logging in i3

Tags: scripting, x11, security, i3, screen-lock

Running Manjaro with i3wm, and my `.i3/config` has the following related to locking the screen:

```
# Lock screen
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock -- ~/.i3/lock.sh
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+l exec --no-startup-id i3exit lock
bindsym $mod+9 exec --no-startup-id blurlock
```

The script `lock.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
xset s off dpms 0 10 0
i3lock --color=4c7899 --ignore-empty-password --show-failed-attempts --nofork
xset s off -dpms
```

[Similar to this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered) I want to have a picture taken via a script every time the screen is unlocked. I've written a script that captures a picture from the local webcam, and this works perfectly fine - **how do I alter the above setup to have the script run after unlocking my screen?**

I hope this can be done at the level of the `.i3/config` rather than messing with `pam.d` files like the answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some digging around the Arch Wiki and web pages for the other packages, I realized I didn't have to adjust any of the `pam.d` config files at all.

`blurlock` is simply an `i3lock` wrapper that blurs the screen, so I can use the `i3lock` `-n` option in combination with my picture taking script.

This is the line in my `.i3/config`:

`bindsym $mod+9 exec --no-startup-id "blurlock -n && auth_picture"`

Similarly, I can adjust the `lock.sh` script to run `auth_picture` after the screen has been unlocked after suspension.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
xset s off dpms 0 10 0
i3lock --color=4c7899 --ignore-empty-password --show-failed-attempts --nofork
auth_picture
xset s off -dpms
```