# Use `xautolock` to run script which captures image with `ffmpeg` after unlocking

Tags: ffmpeg, i3, screen-lock

I'm using `i3wm` and I want a script to run after I've unlocked my
screen. I can get this to work when I manually lock my screen,
e.g. using the steps outlined in
[this
post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664763/capture-picture-after-unlocking-screen-logging-in-i3).

But I can't get this to work after my screen is automatically unlocked,
e.g. via `xautolock`. For example,

```
xautolock -time 5 -locker "blurlock -n && my_script.sh"
```

doesn't work – the screen locks after 5 minutes, but the script is not
run after unlock. In fact, it doesn't seem to be run at all.

Is there some way to get this to work? Maybe using `xss-lock` or
similar?

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestion by @aviro in the comments, I changed the script to read

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Hello" >> $HOME/temp.txt
blurlock -n
echo "Unlocked" >> $HOME/temp.txt
```

and then ran `xautolock -time 1 -locker "my_script.sh &"`. The screen locked, and the file `temp.txt` contained both lines from the script. So it is possible to have a command run after unlocking when used in `xautolock`.

Part of what I want my script to do is to capture an image from a camera via `ffmpeg`. I changed my script to the following:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
blurlock -n 
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video-cam $HOME/Pictures/test.jpg 
notify-send -t 30000  'Unlocked'
```

This works when run manually -- the screen is locked, and after unlocking a notification pops up saying "Unlocked", and an image from the web-cam is written to the file as specified.

But when run via `xautolock -locker "my_script.sh"`, after unlocking, there's no image capture or notification. Since I'm running `xautolock` from the terminal (and send it to the background with `&`), I get the following message

```
[1]  + 581665 suspended (tty output)  xautolock -time 1 -locker "my_script.sh"
```

Adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the `ffmpeg` command doesn't help either.

Comment: Instead of using `"blurlock -n && my_script.sh"` (which I don't know if it would work and what is the exit status of `blurlock`, which would determine if the next script runs or not), just create a single script. Inside the script do something at the beginning (write something to file to see that it started running), the next line run `blurlock`, and then at the last line write something to a file at the end (you could also add the exit status of `blurlock`). Run this script manually first to see that it works. Then use it as the `-locker` and see if it also works when `xautolock` runs it.

Comment: Thanks @aviro; I've tried your test with a script that does
`echo "hello" >> file.txt; blurlock -n; echo "unlocked" >> file.txt` as
the `-locker`, and the file is written to appropriately. FYI I think
[this](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/blurlock?h=i3exit) is the script for `blurlock`; it is based on `i3lock`.

Comment: Based on this, I tested a few more things. I removed the `echo` commands from the script, and put the command I wanted after `blurlock -n`; it's actually a line that uses `ffmpeg` to take a picture using a webcam. The script works fine when run manually, but when supplied to `xautolock` as the `-locker` option, nothing happens. I think it might have something to do with `stdout=/=stderr` messages, but even adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` does not fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant details. My comments only intended to get your closer to the root cause.

Comment: Actually, your original question is solved: You can run a script after the lock. Now what happens inside it is entirely different question unrelated to this one.

Comment: For the last problem, just google this error. First result on google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056102/why-do-i-get-suspended-tty-output-in-one-terminal-but-not-in-others

Comment: @aviro I had already found that link -- it's not that it's a problem (I don't intend to manually run `xautolock` from the terminal, it would be launched automatically on login by `i3`), but I thought it might give a hint as to where the `xautolock` problem originates: maybe there is some output of `ffmpeg` to `stdout` or `stderr` that breaks the unlock process.

Comment: Try to run `my_script.sh &` in your shell. I assume you'll see the same problems. Start by checking which of the 3 lines in the script are causing this to isolate the problem and simplify it. Comment out a line at the time until the problem doesn't appear. Then you'll know it's that specific command and you can be more focused. Then you can submit another **new** more simplified question that people are more likely to answer, such as: "If I run `ffmpeg [...] &` in the background, it fails with the message..." (depends if it's actually the `ffmpeg` or something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I'm reasonably sure that using `nohup` before the `ffmpeg` command fixes the problem. That is, the above line in `my_script.sh` should be changed to:

```
nohup ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video-cam $HOME/Pictures/test.jpg > /dev/null 2>&1
```